# hash returns different values to the same file input - Java

Tags: java, hash, md5, dex

I hashes .dex files in java and the output is different between the code in my machine and the same  code with the same file in other machine.There is also a difference with online hash generators.
I've tried changing the encoding but that's not the problem.

Java code:

```
public static String MD5(String md5) {
       try {
            java.security.MessageDigest md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            byte[] array = null;
            try {
                array = md.digest(md5.getBytes());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
              sb.append(Integer.toHexString((array[i] & 0xFF) | 0x100).substring(1,3));
           }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static byte[] readExe(Path path)
    {
        byte[] fileByte = null;
        try {
            fileByte = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fileByte ;

    }
    public static  void write_signature_to_textFile(String location, String data)
    {
        String signLocation = "d:\\Users\\user-pc\\Desktop\\magshimim\\year 3\\signs.txt";
        File file =new File(signLocation);
        //if file doesn't exists, then create it
        if(!file.exists()){
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        FileWriter fw = null;
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(file,true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        try {
            bufferWritter.write(location);
            bufferWritter.write(":");
            bufferWritter.newLine();
            bufferWritter.write(data);
            bufferWritter.newLine();
            bufferWritter.newLine();
            bufferWritter.newLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            bufferWritter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void write_signature_to_binaryFile(String location, byte[] data)
    {
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(location);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            out.write(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void create_list_of_dexFiles(String pathToScan, String ending)
    {
        String target_file = "";
        File folderToScan = new File(pathToScan);
        File[] listOfFiles = folderToScan.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
        {
             if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())
             {
                 target_file = listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath();
                 if (target_file.endsWith("."+ending))
                 {
                     //check whether trget_file product path with / or // . if / write script to change to //
                        byte[] exe_file_bytes = null;
                        String exe_location = target_file ;
                        Path exe_path = Paths.get(exe_location);
                        exe_file_bytes = readExe(exe_path);
                        String string_exe_file_bytes = new String(exe_file_bytes);
                        String result = MD5(string_exe_file_bytes);
                        System.out.println(result);
                        write_signature_to_textFile(exe_location, result);

                 }  
             }
             else if(listOfFiles[i].isDirectory())
             {
                 create_list_of_dexFiles(listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath(), ending);
             }
        }
        return;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        String pathToScan = "d:\\Users\\user-pc\\Desktop\\magshimim\\year 3\\Android Viruses";
        create_list_of_dexFiles(pathToScan, "dex");
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're hashing the same files? It's possible the newline bytes could have been mangled, etc. You could try manually running an existing md5 digest utility on them before running your program, and comparing the output between the machines, and between your utility and the existing utility.

Comment: @JesusFreke I tried that.Different output in each way.

Comment: What outputs were different?

Comment: The 3 outputs-mine,from online hash generators,and from the other machine,are all different from each other.

Comment: If you're getting a different hash for the file itself, using a "known-good" tool in both places (i.e. not using your code), then the file itself is different. You can't expect different files to hash to the same value.